# Ajax acting as GET method even though is POST method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

Hello I have encountered a problem while coding in Javascript and PHP (Ajax non jquery). I am trying to upload a file over Ajax, and handle it in PHP.

This is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP AJAX Upload</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


function upload() {
    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var dat= "bla";
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "working";
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }

    var rad = document.getElementById('fajl');
    var filee = rad.files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('rad',filee)
    formData.append('var',dat)

    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php'); 


    xhr.send(formData);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                //alert(xhr.readyState);
                //alert(xhr.status);
             }       
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="uploadForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload File:</label><br/>
<input name="rad" id="fajl" type="file" class="inputFile" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" onclick="upload()" />
<div id="div2">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['rad']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['rad']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['rad']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
echo ("uspjeh<br>");

}}
}
$podatak=$_POST['var'];
echo "$podatak"

?>
```

Problem is that I dont see PHP script response in my div2 element. Ajax behaves wierd and it puzzles me. I have put JavaScript alert command under xhr.readyState condition (now commented). When I do that then I see the output, but when I close alert dialog, the browser automaticly reloads page and makes the URL like i'm using GET method (i'm using POST) and then server output dissapears. (rad in ?rad=... is the name of my input element)

[image]

When I'm not using alert command then I don't see output at all, because page redirects really fast. What am I misiing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using a submit button and that's submitting the form. By default form methods are GET requests. Change to just a button instead:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" onclick="upload()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The default form action (submitting) is being carried out.

To stop this add `return false` to your click handler:

```
onclick="upload(); return false;"
```

Comment: thank you both, I wish I could accept both of answers...or at least vote up but i don't have reputation yet to do that :)